# How do I install the function MROUND in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-reports

This function `MRound` does not exist in MS Access and you can't just install it.

I am trying to use the `mround` function in an Access
report. The function is not listed in the expression
builder box of built in functions. When I use the
calculation, for example, `=mround([AmountDue],0.05)`, and
run the report, it asks for a parameter `mround`.

Answer (score 4):

You could define your own in a public VBA Module, e.g.:

```
Function MRound(dblNum As Double, dblMtp As Double) As Double
    MRound = dblMtp * Round(dblNum / dblMtp, 0)
End Function
```

Alternatively, add a reference to the Microsoft Excel Object Library to your VBA Project (Tools > References) and define the `MRound` function in a public VBA module as:

```
Function MRound(dblNum As Double, dblMtp As Double) As Double
    MRound = Excel.WorksheetFunction.MRound(dblNum, dblMtp)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `MRound` present in Access, so create your own rounding function.

However, never use `Round` for this, as it notoriously buggy. Thus, use plain math and the data type *Decimal* to avoid errors:

```vb
' Rounds a value by 4/5 to the nearest multiplum of a rounding value.
' Accepts any value within the range of data type Currency.
' Mimics Excel function MRound without the limitations of this.
'
' Examples:
'
'   RoundAmount(-922337203685477.5808, 0.05)    -> -922337203685477.6
'   RoundAmount( 922337203685477.5807, 0.05)    ->  922337203685477.6
'   RoundAmount( 10, 3)                         ->                9
'   RoundAmount(-10,-3)                         ->               -9
'   RoundAmount( 1.3, 0.2)                      ->                1.4
'   RoundAmount( 122.25, 0.5)                   ->              122.5
'   RoundAmount( 6.05, 0.1)                     ->                6.1
'   RoundAmount( 7.05, 0.1)                     ->                7.1

' 2009-05-17. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RoundAmount( _
    ByVal Value As Currency, _
    ByVal RoundValue As Currency) _
    As Variant

    Dim BaseValue   As Variant
    Dim Result      As Variant

    BaseValue = Int(Value / CDec(RoundValue) + CDec(0.5))
    Result = BaseValue * RoundValue

    RoundAmount = Result

End Function
```

This function will, for example, round this correctly:

```vb
Amount = RoundAmount( 122.25, 0.5)
Amount -> 122.50
```

For further information about precision rounding, refer to my project at **GitHub**:

[VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round)

and the articles referred to herein.